# host in cloud .net core

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

I am new to .net core. My understanding, once you develop the code, you can host your deployed code in cloud, whether its AWS or azure. When i started a new project in .net core, it asks me with a checkbox as per screenshot whether i want to host in cloud or not. What's the different if i tick or untick it? in the end, i can always deploy my app in Cloud regardless I tick or untick it. So I don't really understand what's the purpose if I tick the "host in cloud" checkbox. Can someone please assist? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

`Host in the cloud` assists you settings up the publish profile. You can do it yourself, it's the same thing.